# How can I convert matlab code into python code?

Tags: python, matlab, python-3.x, arcgis

Next code is matlab code. I want to convert this code into python code in order to use it in Arcgis.

```
vals = zeros(size(a(:,:,1)));
 [~,indexOfMax] = max(a,[],3);
 for i=1:size(a,1)
    for j=1:size(a,2)
        vals(i,j) = b(i,j, indexOfMax(i,j));
    end 
 end
```

I'll explain briefly explain this code. I have two images (named A and B). Both have 7 layers at the same dimension (4169,6289,7). First I'd like to find the location of max value in A image and then get the value of B image at the location of max value which extracted from A image in previous step.

Thanks a lot

Comment: it seems that using pythons-matplotlib might be a good starting place

Comment: you should look into `scipy` at http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vals = numpy.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[1]))
indexOfMax = numpy.argmax(a,2)
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
  for j in range(a.shape[1]):
    vals[i,j] = b[i,j, indexOfMax[i,j]]
```

It should also be possible to vectorize instead of using the *for* loops.

Be careful, in Python indentation is important! Keep the indentations before the second *for* loop and before *vals*.